# Expanding body with content

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a problem regarding relative positioning. I want the body to have a background color of say, blue. Initially the page should be just of height 100% (that may vary from computer to laptop, of course, hence I can't specify a fixed height in pixels), thus the entire page should appear blue. In the middle of the page is an element, that has been set to that position by relative positioning (it can't be absolute, can it, in order to expand with its content). The element can expand vertically. If the height exceeds the boundary of the page, the page also should expand, the background of the expanded portion being still blue.

Now how do I achieve this? The only solution I can think of is to use relative positioning for the background element (which is blue and should remain blue on expansion). But for that, I must set it to the available height (relatively positioned elements cannot be assigned height through percentage value, so that rules out `height: 100%`). But the height itself will vary depending on the browser, viewport size, etc (and I can't use Javascript!). So how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the height of the element in the middle known?

You might want to take a look at this http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

A live demo that might help http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/7N4Xx/

The JavaScript is just for changing the height of the div in the middle.

Comment: Yes it has an initial height of say 400px, then it may expand. That's where my question lies, if it expands to such a situation where it goes out of viewport, the background div should expand as well. If I could determine the background div's initial height (would have been 100% if absolutely placed, but then it won't expand!), the problem would be solved. Even Javascript `availheight` doesn't give accurate results. I need the equivalent of `height: 100%`...

Comment: Then you should take a look at the last situation discussed in the article I linked to (the situation when the dimensions of both the parent and the child are unknown)

Comment: Ummm, that looks overtly complicated! I always try to not use CSS tables, so I will just encompass the centered element inside another wrapper element, give it a maximum height, and set its overflow to auto. Thanks anyway. The link was great...

Comment: Actually, the one case you need does not use tables. I've updated my answer to include a live demo that might help.

Comment: Well, that requires Javascript, which I said I cannot rely on! Anyway, now I have decided to rely on it, so it will probably work for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can completely remove the JavaScript :) I've mentioned above that it only serves for testing how it all behaves on resizing the block in the middle.